# How to get the list of scheduled job and stop it in Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm using ActorSystem.scheduler.schedule() method, and it can work well
the question is: when I want to stop a scheduled job , how can i find it and stop it?
I went over the documention and couldn't find how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scheduling a task will result in a Cancellable (or throw an IllegalStateException if attempted after the scheduler’s shutdown). This allows you to cancel something that has been scheduled for execution.

Basically, a call to `schedule()` will return a cancellable task. All you have to do is to maintain it and call `cancel()` at some point. [More details here.](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html)

Comment: thanks , but when I created a scheduled job in once a request,how can I get it in another request ,how can i save these scheduled jobs ? and I also have a question that when I restart the application server or system(linux) , how can i get the scheduled jobs back?

Comment: You need to maintain a collection (maybe `Map[String, Cancellable]`) of these jobs somewhere in your code. Jobs would be accessible by `String` key passed by request. This way  concurrency issues and mutable state are introduced. These jobs are stored in memory, thus you cannot get them back when you restart server/OS. However you could re-schedule them when your server starts, see `GlobalSettings` or `Module` in `PlayFramework`.